# WPF how to detach event hooks in UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifycollectionchanged

I have a WPF `UserControl` that contains a `ComboBox`. I need to attach an event listener to the `ComboBox.Items` collection.

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ((INotifyCollectionChanged)comboBox.Items).CollectionChanged +=
        ComboBoxItemsChanged;
}
```

But I cant seem to figure out how to detach it. Or is that handled automatically when the entire control is garbage collected?

Comment: It is perhaps not a bad question, but the intent is dubious. What are you trying to do that you can't do through bindings and/or triggers?

Comment: @Jay: I want the ComboBox to autoselect the first value when the ItemsSource property is set if, and only if, Items.Count == 1 && SelectedItem == null;

Comment: Are you using MVVM or any other presentation pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement IDisposable interface and detach event handler in Dispose method